# One time popup via click on button (not image itself)

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I have a gallery, on each image I overlay some buttons. So I want to make the image popup once in magnfific viewer from click on this button. I want it to show the zoom/enlarge effect from the image to the popup.

This is the code to attach it on click of the actual image:

```
$('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    closeBtnInside: false,
    fixedContentPos: true,
    mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
    image: {
        verticalFit: true
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
    }
});
```

But I just want to do this one time and not on event listener attach. Just like trigger please.

This is a screenshot of my situation:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `$('#your_image').click();` just be enough? If not.. I don't really get you.

Comment: How about [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)?...

Comment: Thanks guys, it doesn't feel right, there has to be an API way I just can't find it, usually its like a "handle" or something - this is opposed to dispatching click.